# Why tab[i][j] = "value" segfault

Tags: c, pointers, tabs, segmentation-fault, int

Why when i do this i get a segfault ? I'm just giving the value 5 to the first place of my int array ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int     **tab;
int     i;
int     j;

i = 0;
j = 0;
tab = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 100);
tab[i][j] = 5;
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have not allocated your memory properly. What you actually have done is allocate only the ***rows*** of your table. You have not allocated any space for the ***columns***, but you still try to access them and this will cause undefined behavior. In order to fix it, replace the part :

```
tab = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 100);
tab[i][j] = 5;
```

with :

```
tab = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 100);
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM) ;   //where NUM is the size you want to allocate
tab[i][j] = 5;
```

Take a look at this [link](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/) to understand how the memory allocation for pointer to pointer works.

---

Also, see [why you should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: For 2D arrays, using this method is always a bad idea. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32050859/584518). Also the link you provided goes to some hobbyist amateur site... I wouldn't look at it.

Comment: @Lundin the OP used dynamic memory allocation so I continued his approach. As for the link, it may be amateur but I find it very simple to understand and explanatory.

Comment: I haven't said that he shouldn't use dynamic allocation, I said that he shouldn't allocate a segmented pointer-to-pointer thing scattered all over the heap, for no reason. While he just wants a 2D array. The link may be easy to understand, but **the contents are incorrect and teaches bad practice**. Again, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050256/function-to-dynamically-allocate-matrix/32050859#32050859).

Comment: @Lundin thanks for posting me an answer of yours, will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

The memory could be allocated with this. Check the return of malloc and when no longer needed, free the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int row = 23;
    int col = 100;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int (*tab)[col] = NULL;
    if ( ( (tab) = malloc( sizeof(*tab) * row)) == NULL) {
        printf ( "malloc failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    tab[i][j] = 5;
    free ( tab);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocating the first part (rows) of your "matrix"

You must allocate the columns then, e.g.

```
#define ROWS 100
#define COLS 100

tab = malloc(sizeof(int *) * ROWS);
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * COLS) ;   
tab[i][j] = 5;
```

And free all at the end in reverse order

```
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    free(tab[i]);
free(tab);
```

Comment: For 2D arrays, using this method is always a bad idea. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32050859/584518).

Comment: @Lundin Surely +1 by me, but OP didn't say it wants a 2D matrix, I guessed it. I based my answer to pointer to pointer allocation. I mean: "matrix" with variable columns width per row. ;)

Comment: The important part here is that we have to stop people from teaching this pointer to pointer method. Most newbies abuse it when they really just need a 2D array, which is complete nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin Well, I agree. I'll apply that philosophy in future.

Answer (score 0):

`tab[i]` is the same as `*(tab + i)`, but the values in your array are uninitialized, so you are attempting to dereference an uninitialized pointer, which produces undefined behaviour.