# Print dynamic 2-D matrix with a separated function

Tags: c, matrix, printf

I can't understand what's happening. I created a matrix following this post:  [Function to dynamically allocate matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050256/function-to-dynamically-allocate-matrix/32050859#32050859)

To print the matrix, I created this function:

```
void PrintMatrix(uint8_t *matrix, size_t nrows, size_t ncols)
{

    // Prints matrix

    size_t i, j;

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) 
    {
            for (j = 0; j < ncols ; ++j) 
            {
            printf("%" PRIu8 "\t", matrix[i][j]);
            }

    printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

This function results in a compilation error:

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
      printf("%" PRIu8 "\t", matrix[i][j]);
```

In order to check the function, I copied the code inside main() and ran it, suprisingly without any problem, so, why it doesn't work when run as a separated function?

Comment: There is no 2D array (aka matrix) in your code. And C does not support _vectors_. Is this C++?

Comment: @Olaf. It is a 2D matrix allocated dynamically with malloc (I don't know if that's to be called a 2D matrix). Yes, it's C.

Comment: 1) C does not have "matrixes". 2) Matrixes are always 2 dimensional. 3) The C equivalent of a matrix is a 2D array. 4) Your code does not contain a 2D array, but a 1D array (resp. a pointer to the first element). How you allocate the array does not change the type to use. You can very well aloocate a 2D array of arbitrary size with `malloc`. But you need the correct type. A pointer to pointer is a very different datastructure. 5) Not following language rules does not chaange it. C is not very type-safe, but there are still some rules you have to follow. 6) If you want a matrix, use a 2D array.

Comment: See the answer of haccks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix` is of type `uint8_t *`. It should be of type `uint8_t (*)[ncols]` if you are passing the array to the function call (which will convert to pointer to array).

Change

```
void PrintMatrix(uint8_t *matrix, size_t nrows, size_t ncols)
```

to

```
void PrintMatrix(size_t nrows, size_t ncols, unit8_t (*matrix)[ncols])
```

Comment: If so, the function call should be `PrintMatrix(nrows, ncols, matrix)` am I right?

Comment: Yes. That's how it should be called.

Comment: Note: For documentation purposes, it is better to use the equivalent(!) `uint8_t matrix[nrows][ncols]` for the 2D array (i.e. the same as if you declare the array as variable).

Comment: @Olaf. In this second  case is "matrix" still being passed by reference to the "PrintMatrix" function?

Comment: @C.P. C does not support pass by reference. It is strictly pass by value.

Comment: @C.P.: That's why I wrote "equivalent" and mentioned documentation purposes. The semantics are identical; `array` is a pointer, it is just more clear what you expect and what the dimensions are. Also the compiler might be able to apply more checks as can static code checkers and documentation tools like Doxygen can extract more information. All pros, no cons.