# Dynamic Memory Allocation for Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

Currently I am working on a code that computes the following equation with two matrices, X and Y, to return the value of matrix W.

W = (XT * X)^-1 * XT * Y

Input Matrix train:

```
4
10
3.000000,1.000000,1180.000000,1955.000000,221900.000000
3.000000,2.250000,2570.000000,1951.000000,538000.000000
2.000000,1.000000,770.000000,1933.000000,180000.000000
4.000000,3.000000,1960.000000,1965.000000,604000.000000
3.000000,2.000000,1680.000000,1987.000000,510000.000000
4.000000,4.500000,5420.000000,2001.000000,1230000.000000
3.000000,2.250000,1715.000000,1995.000000,257500.000000
3.000000,1.500000,1060.000000,1963.000000,291850.000000
3.000000,1.000000,1780.000000,1960.000000,229500.000000
3.000000,2.500000,1890.000000,2003.000000,323000.000000
```

Input Matrix test:

```
3
3.000000,2.500000,3560.000000,1965.000000
2.000000,1.000000,1160.000000,1942.000000
3.000000,1.000000,1430.000000,1927.000000
```

Result Matrix:

```
716559
194430
323391
```

My code returns the proper values for the testcases with the exception of matrices over the size of 1000.  I know this is because the size is not dynamically allocated, but I am not sure what the best approach to doing this in my code would be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        if(argc < 3){
                printf("error.");
                return 0;
        }
        FILE *fptrain = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(fptrain == NULL)
        {
                printf("error.");
                return 0;
        }
        int row, col, i, j;
        fscanf(fptrain, "%d", &col);
        col = col+1;
        fscanf(fptrain, "%d", &row);
        char ch;
        //creates the original X and Y matrix

        double trainX[row][col];
        double trainY[row][1];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                trainX[i][0] = 1.000000;
                for(j=1; j<col; j++)
                {
                        fscanf(fptrain, "%lf%c", &trainX[i][j], &ch);
                }
                        fscanf(fptrain, "%lf%c", &trainY[i][0], &ch);
        }
        //creates the X transposed matrix
        double trainXtrans[col][row];
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                        trainXtrans[j][i] = trainX[i][j];
                }
        }
        //multiplies X and X transposed
        double trainXtemp[row][row];
        int s;
        double num=0;
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                        for(s=0; s<row; s++)
                        {
                                num = num +  trainX[s][j]*trainXtrans[i][s];
                        }
                        trainXtemp[i][j] = num;
                        num = 0;
                }
        }
        //finds the identity matrix of X times X transposed
        double trainXinden[col][col*2];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                        trainXinden[i][j] = trainXtemp[i][j];
                }
                for(j=col; j<col*2; j++)
                {
                        if(j==i+col)
                        {
                                trainXinden[i][j] = 1.000000;
                        }
                        else{
                                trainXinden[i][j] = 0.000000;
                        }
                }
        }
        //finds the inverse of X times X transposed through Gauss Jordan Elimination
        int k;
        double divscalar;
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                divscalar = trainXinden[i][i];
                for(j=0; j<col*2; j++)
                {
                        if(trainXinden[i][j] != 0)
                        {
                                trainXinden[i][j] = trainXinden[i][j]/divscalar;
                        }
                }
                for(k=0; k<col; k++)
                {
                        if(i!=k)
                        {
                                double subscalar = trainXinden[k][i];
                                for(j=0; j<col*2; j++)
                                {
                                        trainXinden[k][j] = trainXinden[k][j] - subscalar*trainXinden[i][j];
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        double trainXinverse[row][row];       
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)          
        {        
                for(j=0; j<col; j++)              
                {        
                        trainXinverse[i][j] = trainXinden[i][j+col];            
                }        
        }        
        double trainXinvXt[col][row];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(j=0; j<row; j++)                  
                {                
                        for(s=0; s<col; s++)
                        {        
                                num = num + trainXinverse[i][s]*trainXtrans[s][j];
                        }
                                trainXinvXt[i][j] = num;
                                num = 0;
                }
        }
        //multiples (trainXinvXt) by Y
        double weight[row][1];
        for(i=0; i<col; i++)
        {
                for(s=0; s<row; s++)
                {
                        weight[i][0] +=  trainXinvXt[i][s]*trainY[s][0];
                }
        }

        FILE *fptest = fopen(argv[2], "r");
        if(fptest == NULL)
        {
                printf("error.");
                return 0;
        }
        int testrows;
        fscanf(fptest, "%d", &testrows);
        //creates the test file matrix

        double testM[testrows][col];
        for(i=0; i<testrows; i++)
        {
                testM[i][0] = 1.000000;
                for(j=1; j<col; j++)
                {
                        fscanf(fptest, "%lf%c", &testM[i][j], &ch);
                }
        }


        double prices[testrows][1];
        for(i=0; i<testrows; i++)
        {
                for(s=0; s<col; s++)
                {
                        num = num + testM[i][s]*weight[s][0];
                }
                prices[i][0] = num;
                num = 0;
        }

        for(i=0; i<testrows; i++)
        {
                printf("%0.0lf", prices[i][0]);
                printf("\n");
        }
return 0;
}
```

When I use malloc on each matrix, for some reason it appears that it is not allowing me to create the augmented matrix or perform my gauss-jordan reduction, which is ruining my final answer.

Comment: Ugh!  Haven't you heard of functions?  You should be using them.

Comment: Anyway, you allocate the memory with `malloc()`.  What's the trouble?  What have you tried?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have tried using a for loop with matrix[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*row) for each matrix, but this broke my code and caused more segmentation faults

Comment: I can't even compile this code on VS2013.  What are you using to compile it?

Comment: @jwdonahue I am writing this code in SSH

Comment: @jwdonahue: The code is using C99 features (notably variable length arrays, or VLAs) that may not be supported by MS Visual Studio, which is still (depressingly) primarily a C90 compiler with some extra features from C99 and/or C11.  Note that in C11, VLA support is optional; it is mandatory in C99.

Comment: @JoeCur: It would be helpful to have sample data files in a small size (say 10x10 or thereabouts) so that we don't have to guess or deduce the format of the data.  Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — the input data and expected output is an important part of an MCVE.

Comment: Is it just me, or when I see `4` read as `col` and `10` read as `row` I would expect a `10x4` *Input Matrix train* data set, but I see `10x5`, and in your code, you create a `10x4` 2D VLA `trainX`, but then fill the first col with `1.000` leaving you reading 3-cols of data out of the `5` from your input data into `trainX` -- WTF? `fscanf`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, 10x4 initially, and then we are meant to add a column of 1s to make it a 10x5, but that is besides the point

Comment: But do you know your `fscanf(fptrain, "%lf%c", &trainX[i][j], &ch);` would be wrapping from row 1 to row 2 to read `i = 1`, etc.? I guess it's just an example data mismatch, but is sure looks wonky.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to allocate memory to a multi-dimensional array (taking e.g. of 2D array, since you are using matrix in your program):

```
int(*matrix)[col] = malloc (sizeof(int[row][col]));
```

If you want to write a function for it then:

```
void* allocMatrix (int row, int col)
{
    return malloc (sizeof(int[row][col]));
}
```

If you are not familiar with this approach of allocating memory dynamically to a multi-dimensional array then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050256/function-to-dynamically-allocate-matrix/32050859#32050859) (very nicely explained by Lundin).

In your program, you are having the matrix of type `double`, so the `allocMatrix()` will be -

```
void* allocMatrix (int row, int col)
{
    return malloc (sizeof(double[row][col]));
}
```

and in `main()`, you need to make following changes to create matrix dynamically -

```
double (*trainX)[col] = allocMatrix (row, col);
```

Do same changes for other matrices also and make sure to `free()` the dynamically allocated memory to matrices at appropriate places in your program.

Just for the knowledge purpose, [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) practice of allocating memory to the multi-dimensional array has been followed commonly, though it's not the best.

Comment: I am being told that the initialization makes a pointer from an integer without a cast, that there are conflicting types for allocMatrix, and previous implicit declaration, when commenting out trainX and trainY and placing int(*trainX)[col] = allocMatrix(row, col); along with its trainY counterpart beneath the commented out matrices

Comment: @JoeCur I tried making changes in your program for `trainX` and I am not getting any warning message. Please let me know which compiler you are using. Also, in your program, `trainX` is of type `double` but in your comment you have mentioned that you are placing `int(*trainX)[col]...`. Change `int` to `double`.

Comment: @JoeCur: this should work.  But it is hard for anyone to test your code because we don't have a minimal data set, and the layout is curious, at best.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ill add it just for <3

Comment: Thanks!  That'll help.  And size 3 is fine; anything small enough to be easy is fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler edited it with input data and included the problems I am having now with malloc

Comment: @JoeCur: Thanks.  I'm getting some odd results from my code, with it sometimes working and sometimes producing spurious numbers.  I suspect it is 'address space layout randomization' kicking in and doing its stuff, but I've had the same binary run consecutively giving me correct and incorrect results.  That's infuriating — I'm only grateful that I spotted it before sending the code to you.

Comment: @JoeCur: Please make sure that the `allocMatrix()` should allocate memory to the matrix of type `double`.  So, the statement will be - `return malloc (sizeof(double[row][col]));`. With this, I am getting the desired output for the given input that you have specified in your question when I am allocating memory dynamically to matrices in your program.

Comment: @H.S. by adding malloc I am able to handle the oversized arrays, but now I am having issues with creating the augmented matrix as it is not adding the 1.000000s as it is supposed to

Comment: @H.S. it is also no longer multiplying properly, why is this?

Comment: @JoeCur: I am getting the exact same "Result Matrix" for the given input after adding code for dynamic memory allocation. The `malloc` has nothing to do with the multiplying logic.